# Refresh a tableView in a special tab which is connected using Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabbarController which contains 4 tabs. the fourth one connects to a viewController which has navigationController

I want to refresh a tableView in it, whenever user press the fourth tab.

I cannot do it because there is a NavigationController between my UITabbarController and the fourth tab which contains table view

Is there any way to do it?

I have didSelect func in my UITabbaarController and there I call refreshList func but I know it is wrong

```
 override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {


    FourthViewController().RefreshList()

    }
```

Comment: I would do this in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: @dasdom thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

Done,

In fourth view controller I did this

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    didBecomeActive()
}
```

in viewDidLoad

```
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
```

and didBecomeActive

```
public func didBecomeActive() {

    print("did become active")

    let sentMessageBiz = ServiceFactory.CreateInstace(type: SentMessageBusiness.self)


    messages = sentMessageBiz.FetchAll()

    if (tableView != nil && (tableView.delegate as? FourthViewController) != nil)
    {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Comment: You should always call `super.viewWillAppear(animated)` in your implementation of `viewWillAppear(_:)`.

Comment: @dasdom oh ok I added, but Xcode doesn't generate `super.viewWillAppear(animated)`

Comment: Xcode does not generate all cade that is "needed" or recommended.